# How to parse a list of text separated by multi-character delimeters

Tags: antlr4

To parse a comma separated list of text (no comma escapes allowed) I can use this,

```
main: Text (Sep Text)*;

Sep: ',';
Text: ~','*;
```

Now I'd like to modify the parser to use two commas instead of one as a separator.

Clearly this doesn't work,

```
main: Text (Sep Text)*;

Sep: ',,';
Text: ~',,'*;
```

How can I accomplish this? Is it possible for the lexer to return a single token with the text? And is it possible without actions\predicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't negate 2 (or more) characters (`~',,'` is invalid).

You could do this:

```
main  : Text (sep Text)* EOF;
sep   : Comma Comma;
Comma : ',';
Text  : ~',' ( ~',' | ',' ~',' )*;
```

Where `Text` matches a non-comma (`~','`), followed by zero or more:

- non-commas (`~','`), or
- a single comma, followed by a non-comma (`',' ~','`)